# How to update the data plot in a Bokeh app

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I am having a Pandas DataFrame with a TimeSeries Index. The idea is to use the bokeh server in order to have a DateSlider. This means the values that I pass over the function are dates. However, I think my problem is the data is not updated when I am running the bokeh server. The Slider appears but the data is not updating while moving the cursor from the Slider. I would like to have your view. This is my code:

```
#The file was already imported and cleaned as DF: trt_file 

day_one  = str(min(trt_file.index)) #Checking point file
day_last = str(max(trt_file.index)) #Checking point file

# Creating the data source which will be selected from the whole file

source = ColumnDataSource(data={
    "x"            : trt_file.loc[day_one]["Depth [m]"],
    "y"            : trt_file.loc[day_one]["Temperature"],
    "Temperature"  : trt_file.loc[day_one]["Temperature"],
    "Depth"        : trt_file.loc[day_one]["Depth [m]"]
})

#Minimum values for axis generation
xmin, xmax = min(trt_file["Depth [m]"]), max(trt_file["Depth [m]"])
ymin, ymax = min(trt_file["Temperature"]), max(trt_file["Temperature"])

#Set the figure fopr the initial draw
p = figure(title="2018-07-09", x_axis_label="Depth [m]", y_axis_label="Temperature", plot_height=300, plot_width=1500, x_range=(xmin, xmax), y_range=(ymin, ymax),tools=[HoverTool(tooltips=[("Temperature", "@Temperature"), ("Depth [m]", "@Depth")])]  )

#Draw the values from the source we defined first
p.circle(x="x", y="y", fill_alpha=0.5, source=source)

#Set the axis names
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Kable lenght [m]"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "Temperature [C]"

#Creating the DateTime for the Slider
day_one_dt = (min(trt_file.index)) #Checking point file
day_last_dt = (max(trt_file.index))

#Slider
slider = DateSlider(start=day_one, end=day_last, value=day_one, step=1, title="TRT Day")

#Creating the bokeh interactive figure
def update_plot(attr, old, new): #attribute to change, old_val, new_val
    #set day for the slider value
    day_start = (str(slider.value)) #Value from the slider
    new_data = {
        "x"          : trt_file.iloc[day_start]["Depth [m]"],
        "y"          : trt_file.iloc[day_start]["Temperature"],
        "Temperature": trt_file.iloc[day_start]["Temperature"],
        "Depth"      : trt_file.iloc[day_start]["Depth [m]"]
    }
    source.trt_file = new_data
    p.title.text = "Day TRT"

slider.on_change("value", update_plot)
layout = row(widgetbox(slider), p)


curdoc().title = "Temp"
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bokeh knows nothing at all about a "trt file" so setting `source.trt_file` is not something Bokeh will notice or do anything with. The property Bokeh knows about and responds to is `data`:

```
source.data = new_data
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked that mistake and corrected it. However still not updating the data. I will be working on this now that I know my source command was not working properly. Cheers!

Comment: I found the problem. My data was in a format DateTime, while Bokeh just accept data in Date format. For instance, my data had to be groupedby and resampled in order to get it in a daily basis. After this, the graph was properly working with the adjustment you have told me. Thanks for the answer, and happy coding !